# How to change date range of Oracle Date Picker in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

For my date picker in Oracle APEX I am somehow getting year range 2077 - 2097. What settings should I have for minimum date and maximum date to get a date range reasonable for selecting date of birth?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On which Oracle Apex version are you on? Is this the native Datepicker item or are you using a plugin?

For native item type, to have a static date to be used as minimum/maximum date, you can select `minimum date: static` and a date value in the format of: `YYYYMMDDHH24MI` or something like: `-1Y`

If you want your minimum/maximum dates to be dynamic, you can create hidden page item with a dynamic value calculated on it, then use item for the datepicker item's minimum/maximum date field.